# How to fix issue with Web Audio API: DOMException: Unable to decode audio data

Tags: javascript, html, web, audio, web-audio-api

I am having an issue trying to play audio using Web Audio API.
I need to be able to play it from an array of bytes I am returning from the server.
If I save those to a file and play it, it plays in the media players, but I keep getting this error when trying from the Web Application

**DOMException: Unable to decode audio data**

I already tried lots of output formats(wav, ogg, mp3), and bitrates, but still get the issue, any ideas?

Tested on the latest version of Chrome and Edge.

Here is the code I'm using

```
var context;    // Audio context
var buf;        // Audio buffer

export function playAudioBytes(byteArray) {
    if (!window.AudioContext) {
        if (!window.webkitAudioContext) {
            alert("Your browser does not support any AudioContext and cannot play back this audio.");
            return;
        }
        window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
    }

    context = new AudioContext();
    playByteArray(byteArray);
}

function playByteArray(bytes) {
    var buffer = new Uint8Array(bytes.length);
    buffer.set(new Uint8Array(bytes), 0);

    context.decodeAudioData(buffer.buffer, play, decodingError);
}

function play(audioBuffer) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
}

function decodingError(error, e1) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided your audio file, but here is a working example with an audiofile from wikipedia (you can replace with your own):

```
context = new AudioContext();
function play(audioBuffer) {
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = audioBuffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start(0);
}
async function fetchAndPlay() {
  context.decodeAudioData(
      await fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Karplus-strong-A2.ogg')
      .then(r => r.arrayBuffer()),
   decoded => play(decoded));
}
fetchAndPlay();
```